# CSS button positions stitched on background with responsive behaviour

Tags: html, css, frontend

For some reason i've got a background file like this with 3 buttons merged, now i'd like to have a transparent button that superimpose over the button image and be responsive. I've tryed with % and with hv but i cannot understand how manage this...
[this is an example of transparent buttons (with red border for debug)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIIy4.png)

[same as before but with different size of the browser window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEnCN.png)

What i'm trying to achieve is to have the transaprent buttons always in the same position of the circles

```css
/* Homepage */
.home-container{

    width:100hv;
    height: 100%;
}
.home-img{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;

}

.ITA-button{
    
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    top: 69.7vh;
    right: 69vw;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%),translateY(-50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ENG-button{
    
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    top: 69.7vh;
    right: 47vw;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%),translateY(-50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.FRA-button{
    
    width: 65px;
    height: 65px;
    top: 69.7vh;
    right: 25vw;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%),translateY(-50%);
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: tomato;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-s">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>IPAD n°2</title>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    <!-- annullo favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
    
    

    
</head>

<body class="animate-in">
    <div class="home-container">    
    <a class="home-img" href="https://ibb.co/HFjFT3s"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/NVMV2bP/S01-Language-Skyway.png"></a>  
    <button class="ITA-button"></button>  
    <button class="ENG-button">ENG</button> 
    <button class="FRA-button">FRA</button> 
    </div>
    
 
   
</body>


</html>
```

this is the css that i'm working on, the image is contained in home-img class

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit further?

Comment: yes my problem is that i have a background image like the example loaded, with the buttons in it, now is there a way to put a transparent button over it and have it always positioned over the image in a responsive way? because if i scale the browser now, transparent buttons that i've placed over move away i'm putting some more images

Comment: first, we need to know what you're trying, so please share your code.

Comment: Good know. All we need to be able to help you is the HTML.

Comment: hope now is good! sorry i'm at the beginning with web

Comment: If you're using an image, how will you tackle if the user is on a mobile? You should try to achieve this with pure HTML and CSS. Otherwise you will end up in all sorts of trouble when all the complications appears because you gone through with this solution of yours.

Answer (score 1):

Why using an image when you can create the whole thing using HTML/CSS

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-top: 200px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
}

.box a {
  transform: translateY(60px);
}

.box a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid #fff;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="">Italiano</a>
  <a href="">English</a>
  <a href="">Français</a>
</div>
```

Example with an image and transparency:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: arial;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1016/800/800) center/cover;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(circle at bottom,#fff 20px, transparent 21px 40px,#fff 41px)  top,
     radial-gradient(circle at top   ,#fff 20px, transparent 21px 40px)            bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:calc(100%/3) calc(100% - 20px),calc(100%/3) 20px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.box a {
  transform: translateY(40px);
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
}

.box a::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  border:1px solid green; /* to illustrate, you can remove */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

body {
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="">Italiano</a>
  <a href="">English</a>
  <a href="">Français</a>
</div>
```

---

With your hacky code you can try like below:

```css
/* Homepage */

.home-container {
  position: relative;
}

.home-img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}

.home-container>button {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: tomato;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ITA-button {
  left: 28%;
}

.ENG-button {
  left: 50%;
}

.FRA-button {
  left: 72%;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-container">
  <img class="home-img" src="https://i.ibb.co/NVMV2bP/S01-Language-Skyway.png">
  <button class="ITA-button">IT</button>
  <button class="ENG-button">ENG</button>
  <button class="FRA-button">FRA</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but i need the other way beacause i've got several images with buttons from the client, forse a local site i know this is not the right way to do It but i wish to know if there is a way to achieve the quick and dirt way

Comment: @LuigiSorbilli convince your client to do it differently. You are going in a wrong direction doing what you want and your client is clearly wrong here but things can be changed. Your client give you and image and you transform it into a HTML/CSS code like I did and you have your result

Comment: Thank you but this would bè the second step. For more clarity take another example: a map image with a size n, in this map tou need to put some buttons over a location and you need that this button is always over this location even if you change the size of the window... Is this possible?

Comment: @LuigiSorbilli yes it's possible check the last update but it remain a very bad and hacky way